# LDAP connections using BIND authentication mechanism

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

If LDAPv3 is being used with BIND authentication mechanism, then are multiple connections created between client and ldap server? Or just multiple sessions?

As per my understanding,
using ldapv3, for a deployed application, only a single connection will be created from client to LDAP server using manager dn and password. Every BIND request from the client using user's login credentials does not create a connection. It just creates a new session - rebinding happens with different credentials over a single connection created using manager dn and password.

Can BIND requests be sent concurrently to the LDAP server over a single connection?

Comment: Yes for ldapv2, each user login creates a different connection. But for ldapv3, is it not true that when client connects using manager dn and password, server sets the connection state as unauthenticated. Once the user binds using credentials, state of the connection changes to authenticated. So using ldapv3, the connection state can change multiple times. Basically Rebinding using different credentials happens over a single connection.

Comment: No, it isn't true. If you've authenticated as the manager, you are authenticated as the manager. Not unauthenticated. The statement doesn't make sense. **And** you should **never** use the manager account. That's for OpenLDAP. You should define an admin account with the correct privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I think we need some context.

LDAP uses TCP as a transport protocol. Once the transport connection over TCP is made, LDAP can then perform a LDAP requests within the TCP Connection.

You can establish a TCP Connection and bind as one user and then bind as a different user of the same TCP Connection.

Of course, TCP connections do die typically when not used based on the TCP Timeout values and maybe closed by either the Client or server. (Or a load balancer in the middle)

ONLY talking about LDAPv3 RFC 4511 (section 4.2.1) states that **bind operations** cannot be processed on a connection that has any other outstanding operations. In particular "Before processing a Bind Request, all uncompleted operations MUST either complete or be "abandoned" and "After sending a Bind Request, clients MUST NOT send further LDAP PDUs until receiving the Bind Response."

LDAP is an inherently asynchronous protocol, **EXCEPT** for BindRequests, meaning that, in most cases, you can issue multiple concurrent requests over the same connection and the client will be able to correlate the responses with their appropriate requests.

Most of the JAVA LDAP SDKs and other LDAP API function calls have both Synchronous Operation and Asynchronous Operation versions.

-jim

Answer (score 1):

This is all completely confused. Bind requests are created over an existing connection. They either succeed or fail. They create an LDAP session of sorts, if successful, but it only lasts as long as the connection it was established with, or until another BIND request. LDAP connections are shortlived in general: they are only there to authenticate the user, or retrieve information about him from the DIT. They are not long-lived or persistent: at least they shouldn't be, if correctly programmed.

> Can BIND request be sent concurrently to the LDAP server over a single connection?

**Nothing** can be sent concurrently to anything over a single connection. The question doesn't make sense. [Multiplexed protocols excluded, but LDAP is not one of them.]

Comment: Yes for ldapv2, each user login creates a different connection. But for ldapv3, is it not true that when client connects using manager dn and password, server sets the connection state as unauthenticated. Once the user binds using credentials, state of the connection changes to authenticated. So using ldapv3, the connection state can change multiple times. Basically Rebinding using different credentials happens over a single connection.

Comment: developer More nonsense. Logins don't create connections. Connections and binds create logins. When you bind as the manager, you are authenticated as the manager, by definition; when you bind as a user, you are authenticated as that user, by definition. Your final two sentences agree with my answer.

Comment: Actually, LDAP does support asynchronous operations and concurrent requests, but not for BIND requests.